# Issue with the use of Position

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Reading the documentation of `Position`, I found there's a possible issue:
`Position` looks for matches based on patterns, which may not be the same as numerical equality:

```
Position[Range[-1, 1, 0.05], 0.1]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Then a possible way to fix this is left

```
Position[Range[-1, 1, 0.05], n_ /; n == 0.1]
```

> ```
> {{23}}
> ```

My question: Is there a way to fix this issue when you have a list of lists? Because I tried something like the above and it didn't work.

Comment: Let me know if I didn't explain it well.

Comment: You should give an example of *"I tried something like the above and it didn't work"* because it *should* work, e.g. `Position[{{1., 2., 3.}, {4., 5., 6.}}, n_ /; n == 5]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want equality, use rational numbers rather than floating point:

```
Position[Range[-1, 1, 1/20], 1/10]
{{23}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Nearest[Range[-1, 1, 0.05] -> "Index", 0.1]
```

> {23}

Alternatively,

```
Position[Chop[Range[-1, 1, 0.05] - .1], 0] (* or *)
Position[Round[Range[-1, 1, 0.05], .05], 0.1]
```

> {{23}}

If you check the `FullForm` of `Range[-1, 1, 0.05]` you see that it doesn't contain `0.1`:

```
Range[-1, 1, 0.05] // FullForm
```

[image]

Comment: Might I ask why the heck it doesn't contain 0.1? It would seem logical that it should.

Comment: @Emy, not sure exactly why.